# Saving map<string,int> to text file

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, dictionary, fopen

I have a string int map and I want to save it to a txt. I have not used c++ in a while and I'm hazy with pointers and such.

```
int WriteFile(string fname, map<string, int>* m) {
    int count = 0;
    if (m->empty())
        return 0;

    FILE* fp = fopen(fname.c_str(), "w");
    if (!fp)
        return -errno;

    for (map<string, int>::iterator it = m->begin(); it != m->end(); it++) {
        fprintf(fp, "%s=%s\n", it->first.c_str(), &it->second);
        count++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return count;
}
```

The issue is that the ints are written as junk characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%s` is for printing strings and you invoked *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type to `fprintf()`.

You should use format `%d` to print `int`.

```
fprintf(fp, "%s=%d\n", it->first.c_str(), it->second);
```

Comment: aha, I knew I was close, thank you. I did try using 'n' instead of 's', did not see 'd'.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<map>
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int WriteFile(string fname, map<string, int> &m) {
    
    if (m.empty()) return 0;
    
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open(fname);
    
    if(!fout) return -errno;
    
    int count = 0;
    for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); it++) {
        fout<<it->first<<" = "<<it->second<<"\n";
        count++;
    }

    fout.close();
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    map<string, int> m;
    m["Hi there"]=1;
    m["How are you"]=-7;
    m["I am fine"]=-9;
    m["Yo"]=15;
    m["Code"]=2;
    
    
    WriteFile("testing", m);
    return 0;
}
```

You do need to use pointer notation to pass by reference. You can easily do so just by adding `&` to `m` in function parameters